# non browser based uploads to s3 by users

Tags: amazon-s3

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

"If you have an AWS account, you can interact with the S3 service using specialized tools to upload and manage your files. It is very convenient to have access to this online storage resource for yourself, but there may be situations where you would like to allow others to upload files into your account.

For this purpose, S3 accepts uploads via specially-crafted and pre-authorized HTML POST forms. You can include these forms in any web page to allow your web site visitors to send you files using nothing more than a standard web browser."

This excerpt shows that we can use web pages to allow users of a product to upload directly to s3. However, is there a way we can do this without using a browser based approach. As in, can i develop a desktop application to let my users upload to s3 directly?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Here are samples : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadInSingleOp.html

Comment: @TJ- I want users of my product to upload to my bucket, like this - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

Answer (score 1):

Uploading via a browser is just one way of interacting with Amazon S3. It is also possible to call Amazon S3 APIs directly from your application by taking advantage of a Software Development Kit (SDK) for your preferred language.

See: [AWS Tools and SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/)

You also interact via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), available for Windows, Linux and Mac.